# sql group by function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to only get the line with the highest transactiontime per productId. So In this case I need to get the first line and all the other lines with productid 224 should be gone. How can I fix this? Now I group by NQ but there are multiple lines because the NQ changes by every transaction. I also can not take a SUM because then it would add up everything instead of taking the NQ at that certain transaction time. Help is much appreciated

```
SELECT NQ, ProductId, Product, Warehouse, ProductType, MAX(Transactiontime) as 'TransactionTime'
FROM @MaxTime
GROUP BY NQ, Productid, Product, Warehouse, ProductType 
ORDER BY ProductId
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Are you using Sybase or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1  NQ, ProductId, Product, Warehouse, ProductType, MAX(Transactiontime) as 'TransactionTime'
FROM @MaxTime
GROUP BY NQ, Productid, Product, Warehouse, ProductType 
ORDER BY ProductId

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server @jarlh

Comment: @NayasSubramanian If I use top 1 it only selects the first product, I have a lot of different products from which I need everytime the max transactiontime + the NQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
SELECT  MT.NQ, MT.ProductId, MT.Product, MT.Warehouse, MT.ProductType, MT.Transactiontime
FROM    @MaxTime MT
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  ProductId
                ,       MAX(Transactiontime) AS 'TransactionTime'
                FROM    @MaxTime
                GROUP BY Productid
            ) GR
        ON  MT.ProductId = GR.ProductId
        AND MT.TransactionTime = GR.TransactionTime
ORDER BY MT.ProductId
```

Comment: This might do odd things in the event of a tie for the TransactionTime

Comment: @RowlandShaw, indeed, I assumed there is not going to be a tie. Generally I build my queries like this (or using DENSE_RANK rather than ROW_NUMBER), because if there is a tie, I want to know about it. I don't want ties to escape unnoticed. It all depends on the data, of course.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, grouping by `NQ` is what's messing your result up, because each row has a different value.

If you can assume that latest `TransactionTime` has lowest `NQ` value (which is true with the sample data you provided) you can just remove `NQ` from the `group by` and select `min(NQ)` instead of plain `NQ`.

```
SELECT  min(NQ), ProductId, Product, Warehouse, ProductType, MAX(Transactiontime) as 'TransactionTime'
FROM    @MaxTime
GROUP BY Productid, Product, Warehouse, ProductType 
ORDER BY ProductId
```

I'm afraid that would be assuming too much, and if that's true you will have to use @HoneyBadger answer

Comment: Indeed, that's assuming too much ;) Thanks for your feedback, HoneyBadger's answer is indeed what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE, so that you ensure you get the `NQ` from the same row as the `TransactionTime`, e.g.:

```
;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT      NQ, 
                ProductId, 
                Product, 
                Warehouse, 
                ProductType, 
                TransactionTime,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Productid, Product, Warehouse, ProductType ORDER BY TransactionTime DESC) AS rn

    FROM        @MaxTime
)
SELECT      NQ, 
            ProductId, 
            Product, 
            Warehouse, 
            ProductType, 
            TransactionTime

FROM        Data

WHERE       rn = 1

ORDER BY    ProductId
```